# how to equalize text within textView

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, textview

how can I equalize automatically text&textView? I am using Android Studio

[image of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3dnY.jpg)

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="362dp"
    android:layout_height="283dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#9422C5"
    android:backgroundTint="#34C3A4FD"
    android:text="this is the place where I want to equalize the textView according to text"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.489"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: add your xml code

Comment: what do you mean by equalize ?

Comment: @Learnaholic the textView will be smaller if the text is short, or if the text is longer than textView the block will expand

Comment: @JarinRocks I added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use wrap_content for width and height.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#9422C5"
    android:backgroundTint="#34C3A4FD"
    android:text="this is the place where I want to equalize the textView according to text"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.489"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just "wrap_content" for the width and height attribute. add some padding if necessary

```
    <TextView
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/my_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: thank you!! and what is padding actually? (sorry I am learning new and trying to figure out)

Comment: padding is like inner spacing for your Textview, just try add a bit of padding and change the background of your textview, you will understand what i mean :)